# How to change the global publisher layout

Tags: force.com

UPDATED 2

[image]

UPDATED:

[image]

I have added new fields to the existing page layout or create a new page layout I'm not seeing the changes what I have added but I'm getting the below message on the my page layout.

> Actions on this page layout are currently inherited from the global
>   publisher layout. You can override the global publisher layout to set
>   a customized list of actions for this layout.

How can I override or delete so I can see my page layout changes?

Answer (score 1):

The global publisher layout, which is used on the Chatter tab and the Home tab and any object page layouts that inherit from the global layout, can be edited under Global > Publisher Layouts in the Setup tree. For more information, see [Customize Global Publisher Layouts in the Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizing_global_publisher_layouts.htm).

To override your page layout so that it doesn't use the global publisher layout, click the "override the predefined actions" link in the Quick Actions in the Publisher section. You will then be able to drag actions from the Quick Actions section in the page layout palette into that section. For more information, see [Customize Actions with the Enhanced Page Layout Editor](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=adding_actions_using_ple.htm&language=en_US).

Mobile Smart Actions (which I see in your updated post) are only visible in Salesforce1, and won't show up in your page layout in the standard web version of Salesforce. You need to use real quick actions. For more information, see [Mobile Smart Actions Overview in the Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=smart_actions_overview.htm).

I recommend **not** using Mobile Smart Actions, even if you're using Salesforce1. They use the full object page layout to create new records, and you can't customize which actions are available. Quick actions (aka publisher actions) allow you to create custom forms that can be optimized for mobile; they allow you to use predefined values to populate form fields; and you can even use them in Process Builder. Check out the [Quick Actions Implementation Guide](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/actions_impl_guide.pdf) for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my question and in the global > publisher layouts > I see : Global Layout and when i click on edit I do not see anything under Global Publisher >> Actions in the Publisher

Comment: I added a paragraph on overriding your page layout actions. Additionally, if you don't see any actions in the Actions in the Publisher section of your Global Layout global publisher layout, you can drag them in from the Quick Action section of the palette.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you are describing is due to the fact that there is more than one page layout for the object in question.  After you save your changes to the layout and go back to "view" mode, you aren't seeing your changes b/c you are viewing a different layout than the one you edited.

For standard objects, navigate to Setup > Build > Customize > [Object name] > Page Layouts and click the "Page Layout Assignment" button

For custom objects, navigate to Setup > Create > Objects > [Object name] > Page layouts section and click the "Page Layout Assignment" button.

As to your question about the global publisher layout message, hover over the words "override the global publisher layout" and click the link.  Then you can customize the publisher actions for this layout specifically.

[image]

To add an action to the layout, find the "Actions" section of the page layout editor (Under Fields and Buttons) and drag the available actions on to the layout.

[image]

Comment: You are correct and as soon I click on the hover link (override the global publisher layout) I get a section called "Action in the Publisher", please see my updated question.

Comment: Seems to me you have two questions.  Not sure which one you're still having trouble with.  I guess I could have also told you how to add actions to the layout.  See my updated answer above.

Comment: Also forgot to mention that I do not have more than one page layout I just only have one page layout.

Comment: First, I'm unable to drag and drop and its not allowing me to drag anywhere on the page layout even after adding a section.... but lets take a step back and realized that I do not think I have anything to do with Actions but my main problem is that, if I add any new fields to the existing payout and after save I do not see the changes and if I go back to the page layout and I see the changes that I have made to the page layout.

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look at it.

Comment: Hmm.  That's puzzling.  Are you a System Administrator in this org?  Is it possible that you are editing one page layout, but that you aren't "assigned" to that page layout and thus don't see it when you view the record?  I have been tripped up by this before.

Comment: yes I'm admin on this org .

Comment: yes I'm admin on this org ., so I have `EDIT Page Layout Assignment` and change my layout to new one (with new data fields on it) and select all profiles and still I do not see... its very frustration....

Comment: Are there record types on this object?

Comment: No record types